# What does `$this` mean when used outside class in PHP 5?

Tags: php

I'm migrating an application from a PHP 5 server to a PHP 7 server for a client. I've come across some nonsensical code *that works* (in the sense that it does not throw errors or warnings) on the PHP 5 server but crashes on the PHP 7 server. I'm trying to understand the semantics of `$this` in PHP 5 that would help me decipher what the code is doing:

```php
if ( !is_object( $this ) )
{
    require_once '' . '/model/Model.php';

    $me = new Controller( false );
    $me->invoke();
}
else
{
    require_once 'model/Model.php';
}
```

The offending statement is of course `if ( !is_object( $this ) )`; `$this` is illegal outside of a class.  My guess is the code is attempting to instantiate some kind of singleton and can only assume the semantics of `$this` in PHP5 resolved `$this` as `null`ish when used outside of a class. I am having trouble confirming this.

Did PHP *ever* allow this kind of usage? Or was there some configuration option that enabled it to be used this way? What did `$this` mean when used this way?

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't throw any errors? 

I have checked this on my PHP 5 configuration and does spit out a fatal error

Comment: The only edge case I can think of is that the code might be included while inside a class method - the new file doesn't start a new scope, so $this would still be defined. But that would still work the same in PHP 7, so I don't think that's what's going on.

Comment: Timberman - totally understand the skepticism. I'm skeptical too, but nope, no errors are logged. I assume fatal errors result in HTTP 500's? The app neither logs nor errors. IMSoP - yea, that's what I was thinking as well. Thanks both

Comment: Yes, you called it @IMSoP. Buried in one of the thousands of files (many of them duplicates...) in the source, one includes the controller from within a class call and instantiates it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, using `$this` in global scope won't have ever done anything useful*

It was actually PHP 7.1 that made the change - specifically the [Fix inconsistent behavior of $this variable](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/this_var) RFC. Before that, PHP just treated it the same as any other undefined variable. Now you'll see a fatal error instead, see https://3v4l.org/b4Wte

I'd assume that this code was copied from a class method, where it looks like it was trying to run from both a static and object context.

The really quick change would be to swap out the `is_object` check for `isset`, which can still run safely with `$this`. But since the line will always be true, you might as well just replace the whole thing with

```
require_once '' . '/model/Model.php';

$me = new Controller( false );
$me->invoke();
```

* Strictly speaking, all the way back in PHP 4 you could have redefined `$this` to point to whatever you want, but I'm guessing that probably doesn't apply here.

Comment: Thanks for the links, this is exactly what I was looking for!